# How do I reverse text?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on my project and one of its functionalities is to reverse only text (the number should stay as its). For example, the text  **This is a test file**  becomes
**elif tset a si sihT**. Another example that contains digits **USA 123 UAE** should become **EAU 123 ASU**

I write the following program, but the result is not correct, especially for the lines that contain numbers (the problem occurs when English text in the same line is separated by numbers). For example, I got **USA 123 UAE** instead of the correct result **EAU 123 ASU**. Also the sentence **Kuwait Iraq 784 Bahrain** should be **niarhaB 784 qarI tiawuK**, but I got the original one. How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
FileName = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test.txt"
Dim AllTextFile As String = File.ReadAllText(FileName)
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName)
Dim seperatedWordsArray As String()
Dim allTextLines As String = ""
Dim tempTextLine As String = ""
Dim englishSentence As String = ""
Dim someSentences As New List(Of String)
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
    tempTextLine = TextLine
    englishSentence = ""
    seperatedWordsArray = Regex.Split(TextLine, " "c)
    For Each word As String In seperatedWordsArray
        If (Regex.IsMatch(word, "^[a-zA-Z,.:]*$")) Then
            englishSentence = englishSentence & word & " "
        End If
    Next

    englishSentence = englishSentence.TrimEnd(" ") 'Remove the last space that added by the previous sentence englishSentence = englishSentence & word & " "
    If (englishSentence.Length > 0) Then
        tempTextLine = tempTextLine.Replace(englishSentence, StrReverse(englishSentence))
    End If
    allTextLines = allTextLines & tempTextLine & vbNewLine
Loop
TextBox2.Text = allTextLines</pre>
```

I have tried my program using the following text:

*This is a test file*

USA 123 UAE

Trump Tower NY 667

123 abcdef ABCDEF

Kuwait Iraq 784 Bahrain

A sentence is a group of words that expresses a statement, question, command or exclamation

111 Sentence 454 Different Types 777:

Statement, Question Type, Command Type, Exclamation Type

Comment: Remove everything from the question and keep **only** what's relevant. 99% of your code/text there is not relevant to your question

Answer (score -1):

```
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim sTest As String = "Kuwait Iraq 784 Bahrain"
        Dim sRevLine As String = ""
        For Each sItem as String in sTest.Split(" ")
            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsNumeric(sItem) Then
                sRevLine = sItem + " " + sRevLine
            Else
                sRevLine = strReverse(sItem) + " " + sRevLine
            End If
        Next
        sRevLine = sRevLine.Trim(" ")
        Console.WriteLine(sRevLine)
    End Sub

    public function strReverse(sIn as String) as String
        Dim cA = sIn.ToCharArray()
        Array.Reverse(cA)
        return New String(cA)
    end function
```